# How can a file be displayed using UIAlertview in iOS?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am trying to display my license agreement the first time that the user run my application. The license agreement is around 3-pages long. Can I used an Alert to display this message? Does UIAlertView controller has a maximum number of characters that can be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion in this case you should present a view with a `UITextView`. I don't see any reasons for displaying a `UIAlertView` because it does not fill the entire screen and user will feel less comfortable reading from an alertview than from a fullscreen textview. `UIAlertView` was not designed to show very long text, it will cut the text if it's too long and doesn't fit in the bounds of the alertview.

Comment: +1. Let me add that from my experience users take Alertviews less seriously than a fullscreen text with an "Accept" button at the bottom. That's probably because Alertviews are very common and you don't expect a legal agreement to be presented this way while a full screen view blocking all of the app from sight implies importance.

Comment: Thanks, I will use an UITextView. When I tried implementing it using an AlertView, the text was cut off.

Answer (score 0):

No maximum character limit seems to be there in UIAlertView.

but,
 UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.